# Modal using Jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

Hi guys I am trying to create a modal using Jquery and CSS. The problem is with the clicks. I want the modal to disappear when I click anywhere but this it not happening here.I tried using  if(!$(e.target).closest method.

I am sharing my [Git Repository](https://github.com/manurag02/Jquery1)  and my [Git page](https://manurag02.github.io/Jquery1/),

When you click on Launch modal the popup emerges but the background is still active.

Comment: checkout demo at https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h and do accordingly

Comment: @AnilPanwar Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. In this case the Bootstrap documentation is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that for representation purpose only, though you are right, we should avoid W3School  as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following click event

```
$('body').on('click',function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).closest('.infobox,#dispmod').length) {//check if the element clicked is the modal body or the children of the modal
      //hide the modal if its not
       $('.infobox').css('display','none');
       $('.container').css("opacity","1");
       $('#dispmod').css("opacity","1");
  }
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5fvb444a/)

Comment: I have tried this earlier but sadly it doesn't works.

Comment: what doesn't word exacly?

Comment: 1. Click on the modal button 2. Pop up emerges 3. Click  on the modal button or Dropdown button we are able to do it. Ideally we should not be able to pull the dropdown or click anywhere.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5fvb444a/  here the collapsible group item is still active when the modal is up. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It is working perfectly now. It was all due to 'return false'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your target should be up to body.

```
$("body").on("click", function(){ // Your Style goes here}
```

Comment: Thank you.. @Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the click event given by @anurag-mishra .
Then have backdrop css like this.

```
{
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7);
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
}
```

This will prevent clicking on other elements like dropdown button in your example.

Prepend a div to the body with the class called backdrop.

Whenever the modal is closed remove the backdrop div.